# Vlookup in VBA from different sheets - coding error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

i am new to VBA. I got this code but when it runs, it shows this error message :

> Wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment.

This is my code when i copied it from somewhere and editing myself :

```
Sub cl_macro2() 
    cl_macro2 macro '
    Dim Concur As Worksheet, SunAccCode As Worksheet
    Dim ConcurLastRow As Long, SunAccCodeLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim SunAccCodeRng As Range

    Set Concur = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Concur")
    Set SunAccCode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SunAccCode")

    ConcurLastRow = Concur.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    SunAccCodeLastRow = SunAccCode.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set SunAccCodeRng = SunAccCode.Range("A1:C" & SunAccCodeLastRow)

    For x = 2 To ConcurLastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    Concur.Range("J" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Concur.Range("I" & x).Value, SunAccCodeRng, 3, 0)

    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Sub cl_macro2()


cl_macro2 macro
'
    Dim Concur As Worksheet, SunAccCode As Worksheet
    Dim ConcurLastRow As Long, SunAccCodeLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim SunAccCodeRng As Range

Comment: The yellow pointer line is at Sub cl_macro2()

Comment: I'll edit your question to see if I understand what you mean. Is that what it looks like? If so, remove the 2nd line. If that's not what it looks like, please edit your question to make it look like what it looks like in your code window. Do not post the code in a comment.

Comment: Thanks braX!! It's successful after i delete the second line. Wondering why this happen but sometimes it can ?

Comment: comments should be *preceded* with a ' symbol

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your code reads:

```
cl_macro2 macro '
```

This appears to be a (meaningless) comment, but without the apostrophe at the beginning of the line telling VBA not to execute it.

What's actually happening is that VBA is trying to execute this line as if it were code. As written, it means the sub is trying to call itself - and pass an argument (variable) called "macro". But since the sub doesn't take any arguments, you get an error.

For a comment, you need to insert a ' like this:

```
' cl_macro2 macro '
```

Otherwise, just delete the whole line.